# Checkbox Find By Attribute name and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my page I have several groups of checkboxes. In a certain group of checkbox, I added "documentcategory" attribute to each checkbox. I want to find all checkboxes in my page that have "documentcategory" attribute and its value is "BUY".  Please help. Here's my approach.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Documents[0].Checked" id="Documents_0" documentcategory="BUY">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Documents[1].Checked" id="Documents_1" documentcategory="">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Documents[2].Checked" id="Documents_2" documentcategory="">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Documents[3].Checked" id="Documents_3" documentcategory="BUY">
```

**jQuery**

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").find("[attribute='documentcategory']").contains('BUY')
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: $(...).find(...).contains is not a function
```

I also tried other approach. They don't have error but there's no result.

Comment: try `.find("[documentcategory=BUY]")`

Comment: why dont you use data-attribute ?

Comment: `.contains()` isn't doing what you think it's doing. [Here are the docs for it](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like following.

```
$(":checkbox[documentcategory=BUY]")
```

Answer (score 2):

[contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains) method is used to check its text/element not element's attribute.

You can chain the attribute equal selector like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][documentcategory="BUY"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][documentcategory='BUY']");
```

```js
 console.log($("input[type=checkbox][documentcategory='BUY']").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Documents[0].Checked" id="Documents_0" documentcategory="BUY">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Documents[1].Checked" id="Documents_1" documentcategory="">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Documents[2].Checked" id="Documents_2" documentcategory="">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Documents[3].Checked" id="Documents_3" documentcategory="BUY">
```

Answer (score 0):

can try by `.attr(attr-name)` ....

```
$("input").each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('documentcategory') == "BUY") {
       //exist BUY 
   };   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this example for using checkbox each loop and get all checkbox id who have "documentcategory" attribute and it's value "BUY"

<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Documents[0].Checked" id="Documents_0" documentcategory="BUY">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Documents[1].Checked" id="Documents_1" documentcategory="">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Documents[2].Checked" id="Documents_2" documentcategory="">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Documents[3].Checked" id="Documents_3" documentcategory="BUY">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        var cust_attr=$(this).attr('documentcategory');
        if(cust_attr=='BUY')
        {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        }       
     });
</script>
```